# Looping back and forth a list within a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am given a problem where I have to loop back and forth a 5x5 list within a list. So I created a list within a list where all the elements are 0 for convenience:

```
lst = [[0 for x in range(6)] for y in range(6)]
print(lst)
```

which will give me:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I have to be able to start from any coordinate in this nested list, for exmaple lst[3][2] then keep checking each coordinate lst[3][3], lst[3][4], lst[3][4], lst[4][0],... and so forth until I reach the maximum which islst[4][4] after which I have to loop back to lst[4][3], lst[4][2], lst[4][1],... until it reaches lst[0][0] after which I have to loop back up again. It's like an infinite loop where I start in a certain spot then loop endlessly back and forth until I tell it to stop.

I can do a nested loop but it stops at lst[4],[4]:

```
for x in range(len(lst)):
    for y in range(len(lst)):
        lst[x][y] = do something
```

I can tweak the ranges to start at a specific coordinate but I can't create an infinite loop that will keep looping back and forth. I tried adding a while loop too:

```
while True:
    for x in range(len(lst)):
        for y in range(len(lst)):
            lst[x][y] = do something
```

but after it loops completely it starts over from lst[0][0] not lst[4][3]. Not to mention it starts from the starting point I decided on.

Comment: First - The max is [5][5], not [4][4]. Second - you want to reverse direction at the end, not loop. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes I would like to reverse the direction at the end. I am sorry for the [4][4] I created the loop within a loop wrong

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to deal with the location if you treat the location in the array as a linear location and compute x,y:

```
import random

MAX_X,MAX_Y = 3,3
L = [[0] * MAX_Y for _ in range(MAX_X)]

# Initial array values
cnt = 1
for x in range(MAX_X):
    for y in range(MAX_Y):
        L[x][y] = cnt
        cnt += 1

print(L)

# Pick a linear starting location
cur = random.randrange(MAX_X * MAX_Y)
d = 1 # direction to advance
while True:
    x,y = divmod(cur,MAX_Y) # compute x,y from linear location
    print(f'{x},{y} = {L[x][y]}')
    cur += d  # advance in direction

    # if went off either end, reverse direction
    if cur == MAX_X * MAX_Y or cur == -1: 
        d = -d
        cur += 2 * d # stepped one off the wrong way, so go back two.
```

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
2,0 = 7
2,1 = 8
2,2 = 9
2,1 = 8
2,0 = 7
1,2 = 6
1,1 = 5
1,0 = 4
0,2 = 3
0,1 = 2
0,0 = 1
0,1 = 2
0,2 = 3
1,0 = 4
1,1 = 5
1,2 = 6
2,0 = 7
2,1 = 8
2,2 = 9
2,1 = 8
2,0 = 7
  ...
```

Another option if the 2D matrix isn't a hard requirement and the array is read-only is to unroll the loop.  Create a single array with the values from the 2D array in increasing order, then decreasing order.  If you want to start at a particular location in the array, compute the starting location and slice the previous values to the end of the array:

```
import random
import itertools

MAX_X,MAX_Y = 3,3
L = [[0] * MAX_Y for _ in range(MAX_X)]

# Initial array values (same as before)
cnt = 1
for x in range(MAX_X):
    for y in range(MAX_Y):
        L[x][y] = cnt
        cnt += 1

print(L)

linear = sum(L,[]) # Make a 1D array joining all the rows.

# Pick a starting X/Y location
start_x = random.randrange(MAX_X)
start_y = random.randrange(MAX_Y)

# compute its linear location
cur = start_x * MAX_Y + start_y

# slice elements before starting location to end of the list
# and include the reversed array values as well.
unrolled = linear[cur:] + linear[-2:0:-1] + linear[:cur]
print(unrolled)

# cycle through the list endlessly
for n in itertools.cycle(unrolled):
    print(n)
```

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4]
5
6
7
8
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
2
3
4
5
6
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
import time

def showgrid(lst):
   for i in lst:
      for j in i:
         print(str(j).center(3),end=' ')
      print()
   print()


lst = [[0 for x in range(3)] for y in range(3)]  # array all zeros

d = 1 # direction, start forward

x,y = 1,1 # start mid grid

ctr = 1  # data for array position
while True:
   lst[y][x] = ctr # set array data
   x+=d  # next cell
   if x == len(lst[0]) or x == -1: # reached end of row
      y+=d   # next row
      x = len(lst[0])-1-x + d  # move to other end of row
      
   if y == len(lst) or y == -1:  # end or array
      d=-d  # switch direction
      y+=d  # start back
      x = len(lst[0])-1-x + d  # revert other end of row
   ctr+=1
   showgrid(lst)
   time.sleep(.1)
```

Output

```
 0   0   0
 0   1   0
 0   0   0

 0   0   0
 0   1   2
 0   0   0

 0   0   0
 0   1   2
 3   0   0

 0   0   0
 0   1   2
 3   4   0

 0   0   0
 0   1   2
 3   4   5

 0   0   0
 0   1   2
 3   6   5

 0   0   0
 0   1   2
 7   6   5

 0   0   0
 0   1   8
 7   6   5

 0   0   0
 0   9   8
 7   6   5

 0   0   0
 10  9   8
 7   6   5
```

Answer (score 0):

Differently than other approaches, I decided to get the range of all possible x and y (including loop and reverse loop) first, using the `get_range_positions` function. Afterwards I did another function to yield the needed values, given a start position for x and y, and this function I called `get_coordinates`.

At the end, I loop through the list, given the yielded values of `x` and `y`.

```
def get_range_positions(len_first_list,
                        len_second_list):

    result = []

    # loop

    for a in range(len_first_list):
        for b in range(len_second_list):
            result.append((a,b))

    # reverse loop, but we don't want
    # the last and first value again

    f = 0
    l = len(result) - 2

    for i in result[l:f:-1]:
        result.append(i)

    return result


def get_coordinates(start_x,start_y, range_positions):

    # finding out where start_x and start_y is in range_positions
    start = range_positions.index((start_x,start_y))

    # Return X and Y from (start_x,start_y) until the end
    for i in range_positions[start:]:
        yield i[0], i[1]

    # Return X and Y for the entire result_changes, forever.
    while True:
        for i in range_positions:
            yield i[0], i[1]


lst = [[x for x in range(6)] for y in range(6)]
range_positions = get_range_positions(6,6)
print(range_positions)

for x, y in get_coordinates(start_x=0,
                            start_y=0,
                            range_positions=range_positions):

    lst[x,y] = do something
```

Answer (score 0):

You could produce a flat 1D sequence of indices for your 2D list:

```
indices1D = [(i, j) for i in range(NROWS) for j in range(NCOLUMNS)]
```

To be able to go back, attach reversed indices and [use `itertools.cycle()` to repeat it forever](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

```
import itertools

indices = itertools.cycle(indices1d + indices1d[::-1][1:-1])
```

<sup>`[1:-1]` above is to cut/avoid duplicating the turn-around points.</sup>

[To start at a given index, you could use `itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
start_position = i_start * NCOLUMNS + j_start
for i, j in itertools.islice(indices, start_position, None):
    print(lst[i][j])
```

Putting it all together:

```
import itertools


def back_n_forth(seq, i_start, j_start):
    indices1d = [(i, j) for i in range(NROWS) for j in range(NCOLUMNS)]
    indices = itertools.cycle(indices1d + indices1d[::-1][1:-1])
    start_position = i_start * NCOLUMNS + j_start
    for i, j in itertools.islice(indices, start_position, None):
        yield seq[i][j]

# some random 2d list
NROWS = 3
NCOLUMNS = 2
lst = [
    [chr(ord('a') + i) + str(j) for j in range(NCOLUMNS)]
    for i in range(NROWS)
]
for row in lst:
    print(*row)
print()    

# look at the first few items in the infinite sequence
for x in itertools.islice(back_n_forth(lst, 1, 0), 20):
    print(x, end=' ')
```

## [Output](https://repl.it/@zed1/2d-loop-back-n-forth)

```
a0 a1
b0 b1
c0 c1

b0 b1 c0 c1 c0 b1 b0 a1 a0 a1 b0 b1 c0 c1 c0 b1 b0 a1 a0 a1
```